# Adding HTML code into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, html

I'm trying to find a way to add API layers from this HTML code into the MXD file of ArcGIS Desktop 10.3. The HTML file located in my pc:  G:\desktop\y\html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.govmap.gov.il/govmap/api/govmap.api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            govmap.createMap('map', 
                {
                    token: '5a4b8472-b95b-4687-8179-0ccb621c7990',
                    layers: ["GASSTATIONS","health_districts", "KSHTANN_ASSETS", "bus_stops", "PARCEL_ALL"],
                    showXY: true,
                    identifyOnClick: true,
                    isEmbeddedToggle: false,
                    background: "1",
                    layersMode: 1,
                    zoomButtons:false
                });
        });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:1500px;height:700px"></div>
     </head>
 <body>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load those layers in ArcGIS.
The "layers" are provided as a Web Map Service,
meaning you only get the image of where the data is located and the actual vector data which is available for purchase in SOI's (Mapi) website.

You can try and ask someone there if the data is available trhough WMS/WFS as well, which will enable you to open the layer as an image or vector layer in ArcGIS.
If you do get a WMS Server link you can simply add a connection through the catalog in `Add WMS Server`
[ESRI Documentation about adding WMS to ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-wms-services.htm)
[ESRI Documentation about adding WFSto ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-a-wfs-service-to-arcmap.htm) *Requires the Data Interoperability extension